# Why the output of re.findalll and re.finditer are different when using parenthesis?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

In Python 3.6, why re.findall returns different items in the following example compared to re.finditer?

```
text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by 10 caps."

print(re.findall(r"ca(p)", text))

for i in re.finditer(r"ca(p)", text):
    print(i)
```

findall returns['p', 'p'], while finditer returns two "cap". It happens only when I use parenthesis!

Comment: You mean the parentheses at `(p)`? You do know that these are capturing groups? Read the docs on both methods to figure out how they deal with capturing groups.

Answer (score -1):

`finditer` returns an iterable of matched objects which is contain all the captured groups and when you print a matched object it returns the first matched group which is contain the whole matched string.

If you want the string matched by captured groups you need to use `group()` method that accepts the number of captured group as its argument.

```
for i in re.finditer(r"ca(p)", text):
    print(i.group(1))
```

In other hand, `re.findall()` returns strings matched by all the captured groups in your regex in a list. It's roughly equivalent to following `finditer()` code:

```
[i for m in re.finditer(r"ca(p)", text) for i in m.groups()]
```

Comment: Please explain the reason of  your down vote!

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I need to go through group, groups, and `findall()` functionality and role of parentheses in order to understand it. BTW, I didn't give the down vote.